# #1305 - PROCEDURE does not exist в MySQL

Tags: denwer, mysql

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При работе с `MySQL` в этом коде

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure(in p_start_date date)
BEGIN 
select p_start_date as start_date;
END $$;
delimiter ;
call my_procedure('2011-12-16');
```

Я получаю ошибку вида

```
#1305 - PROCEDURE admin.my_procedure does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Вы разделитель не используете...

Вместо:

```
END $$
```

Надо:

```
END $$;
```

2) Если я верно понимаю - после `select...` нужна ';'

3) Ваша процедура - бесcмысленна... Она не возвращает результат

В 1 заход - не работает.. В 2 - работает:

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE FUNCTION my_fn( s_date date ) RETURNS date
BEGIN 
   return s_date;
END$$;
delimiter ;
```

И

```
select my_fn('2011-12-16') as t;
```

Comment: @timka_s, исправил код но ошибка осталась..

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @timka_s, у вас получился результат? У меня выдает ту же ошибку..

Comment: @timka_s, спасибо, разобрался. Кстати ошибка была вот в чем: в имени БД стояла точка))).